# Strip out div with class and keep all other html within

Tags: php, html, regex

My html content:

```
$content = <div class="class-name some-other-class">
<p>ack</p>
</div>
```

Goal: Remove div with `class="class-name` so that I'm left with:

```
<p>ack</p>
```

I know `strip_tags($content, '<p>');` would do the job in this instance but I want to be able to target the divs with a certain class and preserve other divs etc.

And I'm aware that you shouldn't pass html through regex - So whats the best way/proper way to achieving this.

Comment: Have you looked at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm I haven't tried it but looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($content); // loads your HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// returns a list of all links with class containing class-name
$nlist = $xpath->query("div[contains(@class, 'class-name')]");

// Remove the nodes from the xpath query
foreach($nlist as $node) {
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $doc->saveHtml();
```

Comment: This would remove the `p` tag as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the <p> tag because after the query you have the children of the <div> you can do what ever you want at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with some jQuery? '$(".class-name").remove();'